# Custom Adapter Get View , change image

Tags: android

I have a custom adapter which contains custom rows. In these custom rows , i have an imageview and i have to adjust its image resource according to something. It is okay. But when this imageviews image resource is changed in first row , it affects rows which after 'convertview not null'. In my situation after 4th row. I know it reference from convertview and build quickly , but how can i overcome it ? (holder.image3)

```
KanalHolder holder = null;
    final int pozisyon = position;

    Object currentKanal = getItem(position);
    Kanal kanal = (Kanal) currentKanal;
    if(convertView==null) {
        holder = new KanalHolder();
        if (kanal.official) {
            convertView = lala.inflate(R.layout.officialkanal, null);
            holder.image2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            holder.image3 = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button7);
            holder.tv3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            holder.tv4 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
            holder.buton1 = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button7);
            holder.buton2 = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button8);
            holder.buton3 = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
            Log.i("tago", "tagtagatagtagtagatg");
        }
        if (!kanal.official) {
            convertView = lala.inflate(R.layout.normalkanal, null);
            holder.image1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
            holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView8);
            Log.i("tago", "tagtagtag");
        }

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (KanalHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
        if(kanal.official){
            Drawable a = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context , R.drawable.taylanprof);
            holder.image2.setBackground(a);
            Log.i("tago" , "kanaladapter position = " + channelbaba.get(position).getLikedurumu());
            if(channelbaba.get(position).getLikedurumu()== 1){
                holder.image3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heartson);
            }
            holder.tv3.setText(channelbaba.get(position).getKanaladi());
            holder.image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    kanaladi = channelbaba.get(position).getKanaladi();
                    Log.i("tago", kanaladi);
                    kEE = new KanalaElemanEkle();
                    kEE.execute(kanaladi);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, GrupSohbeti.class);
                    intent.putExtra("kanaladi", kanaladi);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            final ImageButton image1 = holder.image3;
            holder.image3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    image1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heartson);
                    image1.setClickable(false);
                    Log.i("tago" , "butona tıklanıldı");
                    String channelid = channelbaba.get(pozisyon).getId();
                    Log.i("tago" , "channel id= " + channelid);
                    officialkanalilikela(channelbaba.get(pozisyon).getId());
                }
            });
        }
        if(!kanal.official){
            holder.image1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.apoprof);
            holder.tv1.setText(channelbaba.get(position).getKanaladi());
            holder.image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    kanaladi = channelbaba.get(pozisyon).getKanaladi();
                    Log.i("tago" , kanaladi);
                    kEE = new KanalaElemanEkle();
                    kEE.execute(kanaladi);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context , GrupSohbeti.class);
                    intent.putExtra("kanaladi" , kanaladi);
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just think of solution sorry for quick question. For newcomers this is needed rearrangement:

```
if(channelbaba.get(position).getLikedurumu()== 1){
                holder.image3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heartson);
                Log.i("tago" , "likedurumu1");
            }else{
                holder.image3.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heartsonn);
                Log.i("tago", "likedurumu2");
            }
            final ImageButton image1 = holder.image3;
            holder.image3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    channelbaba.get(pozisyon).setLikedurumu(1);
                    image1.setImageResource(R.mipmap.heartson);
                    image1.setClickable(false);
                    Log.i("tago" , "butona tıklanıldı");
                    String channelid = channelbaba.get(pozisyon).getId();
                    Log.i("tago" , "channel id= " + channelid);
                    officialkanalilikela(channelbaba.get(pozisyon).getId());
                }
            });
```